# conversion between Mat and Mat1b/Mat3b

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I want to match my code into a given interface. Inside my class OperateImage in all methods I use cv::Mat format. When putting it in SubMain function which  uses cv::Mat3b and returns cv::Mat1b it does not work. How can I change it so that I can use my written class? I am sure there must exist simple conversion which however I did not find, I am beginning in opencv. Thank you in advance for help. Will be very grateful if someone can shortly point out when it makes sense to use Mat1b/Mat3b instead of Mat, what is their role?
(I always saw examples using Mat.)

```
cv::Mat1b SubMain(const cv::Mat3b& img)
{
    OperateImage opImg(img);
    opImg.Trafo(img); // being used as reference in my methods
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mat1b` and `Mat3b` are just two pre-defined cases of `Mat` types, which are defined in `core.hpp` as follows:

```
typedef Mat_<uchar> Mat1b;
...
typedef Mat_<Vec3b> Mat3b;
```

That said, conversion between Mat and `Mat1b`/`Mat3b` should be quite natural/automatic:

```
Mat1b mat1b;
Mat3b mat3b;
Mat mat;

mat = mat1b;
mat = mat3b;
mat1b = mat;
mat3b = mat;
```

---

Back to your case, your problem should not be attributed to their conversions, but the way you define the `SubMain()` and how you use it. The input parameter of `SubMain()` is a `const cv::Mat3b &`, however, you're trying to modify its header to change it to be a `Mat1b` inside the function.

It will be fine if you change it to, e.g.:

```
cv::Mat1b SubMain(const cv::Mat3b& img)
{
    cv::Mat tmp = img.clone();

    OperateImage opImg(tmp);
    opImg.Trafo(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Can someone please answer: ".........when it makes sense to use Mat1b/Mat3b instead of Mat, what is their role? (I always saw examples using Mat.)"

Comment: @herohuyongtao what is the point of using `Mat1b` when we can simply use `Mat`?

Comment: The more you use the hard types, the more errors the compiler will catch for you. Also, you cant use image(row,col) with cv::Mat,

Comment: cvtColor(rgb, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
// note that this also takes care of the weighting...