# Is there a version of Mat1b with CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

When using a equivalent of `Mat` with CUDA we use `cv::cuda::GpuMat`

Is there a equivalent of `Mat1b` to use with CUDA?

Is there a equivalent of `Mat_` as in `GpuMat_`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831081/conversion-between-mat-and-mat1b-mat3b

Comment: @RobertCrovella that question does not deal with CUDA

Comment: @KansaiRobot: But did you read the answer? Mat1b is literally a preprocessor define of a standard Mat with a byte sized type. There would be nothing stopping you from writing one line of code to do the same.....

Comment: @talonmies so that means that *I have to write it* rather than it is there already, right?

Comment: No you don't even have to write it. It just aliases an existing type. Mat1b is just a Mat.

Comment: I mean the CUDA version one

Comment: Do you understand how types work in C++? Mat1b is just an alias to Mat. It doesn't exist as some special type. It is just `Mat<uchar>`. The GPU equivalent is just `GpuMat<uchar>`.  There is nothing magical happening here

Comment: I read the linked answer and it says "two pre-defined cases of Mat types, which are defined in core.hpp as follows:". So clearly those typedef are written in core.hpp. My comments above indicate that I would like to know if something similar exist for CUDA. ergo, is there a XX.hpp where a typedef is written that create the alias we are talking about?

Comment: also there is a template class `Mat_`. Is there an equivalent class `cuda::GpuMat_`?